# Can we fetch server side stats,graphs like CPU, Disk,Memory utilisation, network in grafana for jmeter Tests?

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, grafana

I am using Influx db, grafana setup for Non_gui jmeter tests monitoring and able to fetch response times, throughput, errors stats& graphs. Is it possible to fetch cpu,Memory,network,disk utilisation of app sever side in grafana using any specific dashboard or graphs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any existing solution, you will need to:

1. Install a monitoring software to the system under test side, i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)
2. Configure PerfMon Metrics Collector listener to save the data into a file

   [image]
3. Once your test is done you can import the file generated by PerfMon into [InfluxDB directly](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/write-data/developer-tools/csv/) or using a helper tool like [Telegraf](https://www.influxdata.com/blog/how-to-write-points-from-csv-to-influxdb/)
4. The data from InfluxDB can be visualized in Grafana using a dashboard like [this one](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/10301), you will need to slightly adapt the queries for the panels